# ESP32 and Firestore/Google Cloud Functions

Tags: c, http, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, esp32

I am trying to get data from Firestore onto my ESP32. I want to do this either directly, or by calling a google cloud function (likely python) which will interface with firestore and return data back to the ESP32 through an HTTP get.

Has anyone done this before? And if so, could they give some guidance on how to do that. I can connect my ESP32 to the internet no problem, and I have done HTTP requests to websites that return quotes and such. However, when I change the url to my cloud function url I cannot trigger my google cloud function.

Any information or resources on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please edit the question to explain the specific problem you're running into.  Include code and error messages, along with a description of what the code is supposed to do.  Requests for general hints or advice without a clear mission purpose is off topic for Stack Overflow.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Jonathon, I recommend you to go to [this Firestore guickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers) and after that edit your post to more specific questions.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/cities/LA This was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

if you're working with esp-idf, you don't need a cloud function, you can communicate directly with the Cloud Firestore REST API using this component: https://github.com/kaizoku-oh/firestore